# Trying to get the href attribute value of parent element

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<a class="unfollow_url" href="http://localhost/snapll_back/account/unfollow.php?id=2">
    <div class="unfollow_button_flwrs">unfollow</div>
</a>
```

When user clicks on ".unfollow_button_flwrs" the value of the 'href' attribute of its parent element (".unfollow_url") should be stored in a variable and alerted (for testing purposes).

Here's my JQuery":

```
$(".unfollow_button_flwrs").click(function() {
    var follower_user_id = $(this).parent().attr('href');
    alert(follower_user_id);
    return false;
});
```

However, when I click on the button it just redirects me to the page, even though I have return false and when I add e.preventDefault() it keeps redirecting me too.

How can I solve this?

Comment: 1) Check your console for errors. 2) Are you trying to bind the event handler before the element exists?

Comment: do you have jquery running? this is working fine in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g44deg85/). perhaps some other js is blocking it.

Comment: When you click on `div`, the `a`'s default action is being triggered. I would recommend you getting rid of the inner div, and apply the styling, if any on the `a` itself. That way, it would be easier to prevent the default action, and apply custom javascript to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that you are attaching the event when DOM is ready:

```
$(function(){
 $(".unfollow_button_flwrs").click(function() {
 var follower_user_id = $(this).parent().attr('href');
 alert(follower_user_id);
 return false;
});})
```

**Note:** If elements are added dynamically , then you need to use event delegation for attaching events to such element.

**Update:** Using Event Delegation:

```
$("body").on('click','.unfollow_button_flwrs',function() {
 var follower_user_id = $(this).parent().attr('href');
 alert(follower_user_id);
 return false;
});
```

Comment: The elements are added with JQuery AJAX (post function) with the .html() function.

Comment: @user3608176: there is the problem. You need second approach of event delegation.

Comment: Thanks, it now works with your updated code with event delegation :)

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are adding `e.preventDefault();` to the div.unfollow_button_flwrs class instead of the a.unfollow_url class. Try:

```
$(".unfollow_button_flwrs").parent().click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var follower_user_id = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(follower_user_id);
    return false;
});
```